# how to bind data to a user defined class asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, model-binding

I defined a model look like this

```
public class X { 
int a;
MyClass b;
}
```

and I have an action look like this

```
public IActionResult Test(X x){}
```

now when user submit data I want to manipulate that data and then assign it to b.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the detailed explanation such as how you want to submit data , suppose you have a book model class that contains a child Author property :

```
    public class Book
    {
       public int id { get; set; }

       public string name { get; set; }

       public Author author { get; set; }
    }


    public class Author {
        public int authorId { get; set; }

        public string authorName { get; set; }
    }
```

In your view , using [Tag Helpers in forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1) , you can bind to Author.authorName :

```
@model Book

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RegisterInput" method="post">
    BookID:  <input asp-for="id" /> <br />
    BookName: <input asp-for="name" /><br />

    AuthorID:  <input asp-for="author.authorId" /> <br />
    AuthorName: <input asp-for="author.authorName" /><br />
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

In controller , you will find the input values will automatically bind to related properties :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterInput(Book book)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I submit data by a form.
MyClass is a complex class and I can not use default TagHelpers
assume MyClass is a DateTime (it's totally different with C# DateTime)

Comment: You should provide more details include your codes to help understand your requirement .